# Weird shapes as output( Strings)- C language

Tags: string

So i have a problem. I have to separate the first name, last name and hostname of email.
For example:

zephyr.extreme@gmail.com>> Input

**Output=**

First name= Zephyr

Last name= extreme

Host Name= gmail.com

I am not getting the desired result. I am getting some weird shapes as output.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char email[40], first[20],last[20],host[30];
printf("Enter the email= ");
gets(email);
int i;
while(email[i]!='\0')
{
    while(email[i]!='.')
    {
        first[i]=email[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(email[i]!='@')
    {
        last[i]=email[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(email[i]!='\0')
    {
        host[i]=email[i];
        i++;
    }
}
puts(first);
puts(last);
puts(host);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your output here? Knowing _what_ these "weird shapes" might be would help a lot.

Comment: Also, you should check the return value of `gets`. `gets` returns a `NULL` pointer in case it finds EOF without reading any characters.

(In fact, you shouldn't use `gets` at all - `gets` does not protect you against buffer overflows)

Comment: Then what should i use except     gets

Comment: You should use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) with `stdin` as the `stream` argument. That way you can limit how many bytes you read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format will always be first.last@host..., use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char email[40], first[20],last[20],host[30],name[40];
    int firstDot,atSymbol;
    int i;
    int length;
    char *token;

    printf("Enter the email= ");
    gets(email);
    length = strlen(email);
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){

        if(email[i]=='.')
        {
            firstDot = i;
        }
        else if(email[i]=='@')
        {
            atSymbol = i;
        }
    }
    strncpy(name,email,atSymbol);
    name[atSymbol]= '\0';
       token = strtok(name, ".");

       /* walk through other tokens */
       while( token != NULL ) 
       {
          printf( "%s\n", token );
          token = strtok(NULL, ".");
       }
       strncpy(host,email+atSymbol,length-atSymbol);
    host[length-atSymbol] = '\0';
    puts(host);
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. But i cant understand that last while loop. I understood the strncopy(name,email,atsymbol) part. But what happens next, i can't get it.

Comment: Please read the documentation for strtok: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Answer (score 0):

So i updated the code, now the only problem is the last output.

After host name= gmail.com prints, but then some extra shapes are also printing. These are smile face and some weird symbols.

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char email[40], first[20],last[20],host[30];
printf("Enter the email= ");
gets(email);
int i=0,j;
while(email[i]!='.')
{
    first[i]=email[i];
    i++;
}
i=0;
while(email[i]!='@')
{
    last[i]=email[i];
    i++;
}
j=i;
i=0;
while(email[j]!='\0')
{
    host[i]=email[j];
    j++;
    i++;
}
printf("First Name= ");
puts(first);
printf("Last name= ");
puts(last);
printf("Host name= ");
puts(host);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C strings (`char` pointers) should be [null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). This means your string needs a `'\0'` character at its end so that string manipulation functions such as `puts` or `strlen` know where they end, in constrast to other languages where the string's length is stored together with it. The "weird shapes" you are seeing are just random data stored after the end of the string being interpreted as characters. When you call `puts` it just keeps outputting bytes-as-characters until it randomly finds a byte with value `'\0'`

You can solve this by adding a `'\0'` character to the end of the string after each of the blocks where you write a string.

```
while(email[i]!='.')
{
    first[i]=email[i];
    i++;
}
email[i] = '\0'; //same thing as email[i] = 0; but using a char makes what
                 //you're doing clearer
```

Comment: Hi, just noticed you unaccepted my answer. Did you have any issues?

Comment: No, since i can only select a single answer.